# '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int' transformers pytorch

Tags: pytorch, torch

I am encountering an issue during the training process, which states "Training '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'." I understand that this problem is likely related to the Huggingface transformer library. If you have encountered and resolved this issue before, I would greatly appreciate your assistance.

I have already checked various forums for solutions. One suggestion was to update the transformers version to 4.23.1, but unfortunately, this did not resolve the problem.

```
import logging
from functools import partial
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Any, Dict, List, Tuple, Union

import click
import numpy as np
from datasets import Dataset, load_dataset,load_from_disk

from sample_data.consts import (
    DEFAULT_INPUT_MODEL,
    DEFAULT_SEED,
    PROMPT_WITH_INPUT_FORMAT,
    PROMPT_NO_INPUT_FORMAT,
    END_KEY,
    INSTRUCTION_KEY,
    RESPONSE_KEY_NL,
    DEFAULT_TRAINING_DATASET,
)

from transformers import (
    AutoModelForCausalLM,
    AutoTokenizer,
    DataCollatorForLanguageModeling,
    PreTrainedTokenizer,
    Trainer,
    TrainingArguments,
    set_seed,
)

DEFAULT_TRAINING_DATASET = "./sample_data/databricks/databricks-dolly-15k"
```

```
class DataCollatorForCompletionOnlyLM(DataCollatorForLanguageModeling):
    def torch_call(self, examples: List[Union[List[int], Any, Dict[str, Any]]]) -> Dict[str, Any]:
        batch = super().torch_call(examples)

        # The prompt ends with the response key plus a newline.  We encode this and then try to find it in the
        # sequence of tokens.  This should just be a single token.
        response_token_ids = self.tokenizer.encode(RESPONSE_KEY_NL)

        labels = batch["labels"].clone()

        for i in range(len(examples)):

            response_token_ids_start_idx = None
            for idx in np.where(batch["labels"][i] == response_token_ids[0])[0]:
                response_token_ids_start_idx = idx
                break

            if response_token_ids_start_idx is None:
                raise RuntimeError(
                    f'Could not find response key {response_token_ids} in token IDs {batch["labels"][i]}'
                )

            response_token_ids_end_idx = response_token_ids_start_idx + 1

            # Make pytorch loss function ignore all tokens up through the end of the response key
            labels[i, :response_token_ids_end_idx] = -100

        batch["labels"] = labels

        return batch
```

```
def preprocess_batch(batch: Dict[str, List], tokenizer: AutoTokenizer, max_length: int) -> dict:
    return tokenizer(
        batch["text"],
        max_length=max_length,
        truncation=True,
    )
```

```
def load_training_dataset(path_or_dataset: str = DEFAULT_TRAINING_DATASET) -> Dataset:
    print(f"Loading dataset from {path_or_dataset}")
    dataset = load_dataset('databricks/databricks-dolly-15k')["train"]
    print("Found %d rows", dataset.num_rows)

    def _add_text(rec):
        instruction = rec["instruction"]
        response = rec["response"]
        context = rec.get("context")

        if not instruction:
            raise ValueError(f"Expected an instruction in: {rec}")

        if not response:
            raise ValueError(f"Expected a response in: {rec}")

        # For some instructions there is an input that goes along with the instruction, providing context for the
        # instruction.  For example, the input might be a passage from Wikipedia and the instruction says to extract
        # some piece of information from it.  The response is that information to extract.  In other cases there is
        # no input.  For example, the instruction might be open QA such as asking what year some historic figure was
        # born.
        if context:
            rec["text"] = PROMPT_WITH_INPUT_FORMAT.format(instruction=instruction, response=response, input=context)
        else:
            rec["text"] = PROMPT_NO_INPUT_FORMAT.format(instruction=instruction, response=response)
        return rec

    dataset = dataset.map(_add_text)

    return dataset
```

```
def load_tokenizer(pretrained_model_name_or_path: str = DEFAULT_INPUT_MODEL) -> PreTrainedTokenizer:
    print(f"Loading tokenizer for {pretrained_model_name_or_path}")
    tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(pretrained_model_name_or_path)
    tokenizer.pad_token = tokenizer.eos_token
    tokenizer.add_special_tokens({"additional_special_tokens": [END_KEY, INSTRUCTION_KEY, RESPONSE_KEY_NL]})
    return tokenizer
```

```
def load_model(
    pretrained_model_name_or_path: str = DEFAULT_INPUT_MODEL, *, gradient_checkpointing: bool = False
) -> AutoModelForCausalLM:
    print(f"Loading model for {pretrained_model_name_or_path}")
    model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
        pretrained_model_name_or_path, trust_remote_code=True, use_cache=False if gradient_checkpointing else True
    )
    return model
```

```
def get_model_tokenizer(
    pretrained_model_name_or_path: str = DEFAULT_INPUT_MODEL, *, gradient_checkpointing: bool = False
) -> Tuple[AutoModelForCausalLM, PreTrainedTokenizer]:
    tokenizer = load_tokenizer(pretrained_model_name_or_path)
    model = load_model(pretrained_model_name_or_path, gradient_checkpointing=gradient_checkpointing)
    model.resize_token_embeddings(len(tokenizer)) # model.resize_token_embeddings(len(tokenizer)) is used to adjust the size of the token embeddings in a language model  To match the vocabulary size of a given tokenizer.

    return model, tokenizer
```

```
def preprocess_dataset(tokenizer: AutoTokenizer, max_length: int, seed=DEFAULT_SEED, training_dataset: str = DEFAULT_TRAINING_DATASET) -> Dataset:
    """Loads the training dataset and tokenizes it so it is ready for training.

    Args:
        tokenizer (AutoTokenizer): Tokenizer tied to the model.
        max_length (int): Maximum number of tokens to emit from tokenizer.

    Returns:
        Dataset: HuggingFace dataset
    """

    dataset = load_training_dataset(training_dataset)

    print("Preprocessing dataset")
    _preprocessing_function = partial(preprocess_batch, max_length=max_length, tokenizer=tokenizer)

    # TODO: Are we removing the columns from dataset
    dataset = dataset.map(
        _preprocessing_function,
        batched=True,
        remove_columns=["instruction", "context", "response", "text", "category"],
    )

    # Make sure we don't have any truncated records, as this would mean the end keyword is missing.
    print("Processed dataset has %d rows", dataset.num_rows)
    dataset = dataset.filter(lambda rec: len(rec["input_ids"]) < max_length)
    print("Processed dataset has %d rows after filtering for truncated records", dataset.num_rows)

    print("Shuffling dataset")
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(seed=seed)

    print("Done preprocessing")

    return dataset
```

```
def train(
    input_model: str,
    local_output_dir: str,
    dbfs_output_dir: str,
    epochs: int,
    per_device_train_batch_size: int,
    per_device_eval_batch_size: int,
    lr: float,
    seed: int,
    deepspeed: str,
    gradient_checkpointing: bool,
    local_rank: str,
    bf16: bool,
    logging_steps: int,
    save_steps: int,
    eval_steps: int,
    test_size: Union[float, int],
    save_total_limit: int,
    warmup_steps: int,
    training_dataset: str = DEFAULT_TRAINING_DATASET,
):
    set_seed(seed)

    model, tokenizer = get_model_tokenizer(
        pretrained_model_name_or_path=input_model, gradient_checkpointing=gradient_checkpointing
    )

    # Use the same max length that the model supports.  Fall back to 1024 if the setting can't be found.
    # The configuraton for the length can be stored under different names depending on the model.  Here we attempt
    # a few possible names we've encountered.
    conf = model.config
    max_length = None
    for length_setting in ["n_positions", "max_position_embeddings", "seq_length"]:
        max_length = getattr(model.config, length_setting, None)
        if max_length:
            print(f"Found max lenth: {max_length}")
            break
    if not max_length:
        max_length = 1024
        print(f"Using default max length: {max_length}")

    processed_dataset = preprocess_dataset(tokenizer=tokenizer, max_length=max_length, seed=seed, training_dataset=training_dataset)

    split_dataset = processed_dataset.train_test_split(test_size=test_size, seed=seed)

    print("Train data size: %d", split_dataset["train"].num_rows)
    print("Test data size: %d", split_dataset["test"].num_rows)

    data_collator = DataCollatorForCompletionOnlyLM(
        tokenizer=tokenizer, mlm=False, return_tensors="pt", pad_to_multiple_of=8
    )

    # enable fp16 if not bf16
    fp16 = not bf16

    if not dbfs_output_dir:
        print("Will NOT save to DBFS")

    training_args = TrainingArguments(
        output_dir=local_output_dir,
        per_device_train_batch_size=per_device_train_batch_size,
        per_device_eval_batch_size=per_device_eval_batch_size,
        fp16=fp16,
        bf16=bf16,
        learning_rate=lr,
        num_train_epochs=epochs,
        deepspeed=deepspeed,
        gradient_checkpointing=gradient_checkpointing,
        logging_dir=f"{local_output_dir}/runs",
        logging_strategy="steps",
        logging_steps=logging_steps,
        evaluation_strategy="steps",
        eval_steps=eval_steps,
        save_strategy="steps",
        save_steps=save_steps,
        save_total_limit=save_total_limit,
        load_best_model_at_end=False,
        report_to="tensorboard",
        disable_tqdm=True,
        remove_unused_columns=False,
        warmup_steps=warmup_steps,
    )

    print("Instantiating Trainer")

    trainer = Trainer(
        model=model,
        tokenizer=tokenizer,
        args=training_args,
        train_dataset=split_dataset["train"],
        eval_dataset=split_dataset["test"],
        data_collator=data_collator,
    )

    print("Training")
    try:
      trainer.train()
    except Exception as e:
      print(f'{e}')

    print(f"Saving Model to {local_output_dir}")
    trainer.save_model(output_dir=local_output_dir)

    if dbfs_output_dir:
        print(f"Saving Model to {dbfs_output_dir}")
        trainer.save_model(output_dir=dbfs_output_dir)

    print("Done.")
```

```
try:
    train(
        input_model=DEFAULT_INPUT_MODEL,
        local_output_dir="../local_output_dir",
        dbfs_output_dir="../dbfs_output_dir",
        epochs=1,
        per_device_train_batch_size=8,
        per_device_eval_batch_size=8,
        lr=1e-5,
        seed=DEFAULT_SEED,
        deepspeed=None,
        gradient_checkpointing=True,
        local_rank=True,
        bf16=None,
        logging_steps=10,
        save_steps=400,
        eval_steps=50,
        test_size=100,
        save_total_limit=10,
        warmup_steps=None,
        training_dataset=DEFAULT_TRAINING_DATASET)
except Exception as e:
    print(f'Exception thrown {e}')
```

I am currently using
Torch `2.0.1+cu118`
Transformers `4.32.0.dev0`.

I have attempted both versions, `4.23.1` and `4.6.0`, but none of them were successful.

Below is the Full Stack Error

```
Loading tokenizer for EleutherAI/pythia-6.9b
loading file vocab.json from cache at None
loading file merges.txt from cache at None
loading file tokenizer.json from cache at /root/.cache/huggingface/hub/models--EleutherAI--pythia-6.9b/snapshots/f271943e880e60c0c715fd10e4dc74ec4e31eb44/tokenizer.json
loading file added_tokens.json from cache at None
loading file special_tokens_map.json from cache at /root/.cache/huggingface/hub/models--EleutherAI--pythia-6.9b/snapshots/f271943e880e60c0c715fd10e4dc74ec4e31eb44/special_tokens_map.json
loading file tokenizer_config.json from cache at /root/.cache/huggingface/hub/models--EleutherAI--pythia-6.9b/snapshots/f271943e880e60c0c715fd10e4dc74ec4e31eb44/tokenizer_config.json
Assigning ['### End', '### Instruction:', '### Response:\n'] to the additional_special_tokens key of the tokenizer
Loading model for EleutherAI/pythia-6.9b
loading configuration file config.json from cache at /root/.cache/huggingface/hub/models--EleutherAI--pythia-6.9b/snapshots/f271943e880e60c0c715fd10e4dc74ec4e31eb44/config.json
Model config GPTNeoXConfig {
  "_name_or_path": "EleutherAI/pythia-6.9b",
  "architectures": [
    "GPTNeoXForCausalLM"
  ],
  "bos_token_id": 0,
  "eos_token_id": 0,
  "hidden_act": "gelu",
  "hidden_size": 4096,
  "initializer_range": 0.02,
  "intermediate_size": 16384,
  "layer_norm_eps": 1e-05,
  "max_position_embeddings": 2048,
  "model_type": "gpt_neox",
  "num_attention_heads": 32,
  "num_hidden_layers": 32,
  "rotary_emb_base": 10000,
  "rotary_pct": 0.25,
  "tie_word_embeddings": false,
  "torch_dtype": "float16",
  "transformers_version": "4.23.1",
  "use_cache": false,
  "use_parallel_residual": true,
  "vocab_size": 50432
}

loading weights file pytorch_model.bin from cache at /root/.cache/huggingface/hub/models--EleutherAI--pythia-6.9b/snapshots/f271943e880e60c0c715fd10e4dc74ec4e31eb44/pytorch_model.bin.index.json
All model checkpoint weights were used when initializing GPTNeoXForCausalLM.

All the weights of GPTNeoXForCausalLM were initialized from the model checkpoint at EleutherAI/pythia-6.9b.
If your task is similar to the task the model of the checkpoint was trained on, you can already use GPTNeoXForCausalLM for predictions without further training.
Found max lenth: 2048
Loading dataset from ./sample_data/databricks/databricks-dolly-15k
WARNING:datasets.builder:Found cached dataset json (/root/.cache/huggingface/datasets/databricks___json/databricks--databricks-dolly-15k-7427aa6e57c34282/0.0.0/8bb11242116d547c741b2e8a1f18598ffdd40a1d4f2a2872c7a28b697434bc96)
100%
1/1 [00:00<00:00, 72.80it/s]
WARNING:datasets.arrow_dataset:Loading cached processed dataset at /root/.cache/huggingface/datasets/databricks___json/databricks--databricks-dolly-15k-7427aa6e57c34282/0.0.0/8bb11242116d547c741b2e8a1f18598ffdd40a1d4f2a2872c7a28b697434bc96/cache-f7626aa3304036a3.arrow
WARNING:datasets.arrow_dataset:Loading cached processed dataset at /root/.cache/huggingface/datasets/databricks___json/databricks--databricks-dolly-15k-7427aa6e57c34282/0.0.0/8bb11242116d547c741b2e8a1f18598ffdd40a1d4f2a2872c7a28b697434bc96/cache-4f332844ffcb7c6b.arrow
WARNING:datasets.arrow_dataset:Loading cached processed dataset at /root/.cache/huggingface/datasets/databricks___json/databricks--databricks-dolly-15k-7427aa6e57c34282/0.0.0/8bb11242116d547c741b2e8a1f18598ffdd40a1d4f2a2872c7a28b697434bc96/cache-e15bdeaf5e189e4d.arrow
WARNING:datasets.arrow_dataset:Loading cached shuffled indices for dataset at /root/.cache/huggingface/datasets/databricks___json/databricks--databricks-dolly-15k-7427aa6e57c34282/0.0.0/8bb11242116d547c741b2e8a1f18598ffdd40a1d4f2a2872c7a28b697434bc96/cache-84af7fe5af3e61c9.arrow
WARNING:datasets.arrow_dataset:Loading cached split indices for dataset at /root/.cache/huggingface/datasets/databricks___json/databricks--databricks-dolly-15k-7427aa6e57c34282/0.0.0/8bb11242116d547c741b2e8a1f18598ffdd40a1d4f2a2872c7a28b697434bc96/cache-94ba94f2e119d195.arrow and /root/.cache/huggingface/datasets/databricks___json/databricks--databricks-dolly-15k-7427aa6e57c34282/0.0.0/8bb11242116d547c741b2e8a1f18598ffdd40a1d4f2a2872c7a28b697434bc96/cache-bab7a24701b7b9a9.arrow
PyTorch: setting up devices
Found %d rows 15011
Preprocessing dataset
Processed dataset has %d rows 15011
Processed dataset has %d rows after filtering for truncated records 14977
Shuffling dataset
Done preprocessing
Train data size: %d 14877
Test data size: %d 100
Instantiating Trainer
Using cuda_amp half precision backend
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/optimization.py:306: FutureWarning: This implementation of AdamW is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Use the PyTorch implementation torch.optim.AdamW instead, or set `no_deprecation_warning=True` to disable this warning
  warnings.warn(
Saving model checkpoint to ../local_output_dir
Configuration saved in ../local_output_dir/config.json
Training
'>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'
Saving Model to ../local_output_dir
The model is bigger than the maximum size per checkpoint (10GB) and is going to be split in 3 checkpoint shards. You can find where each parameters has been saved in the index located at ../local_output_dir/pytorch_model.bin.index.json.
tokenizer config file saved in ../local_output_dir/tokenizer_config.json
Special tokens file saved in ../local_output_dir/special_tokens_map.json
Saving model checkpoint to ../dbfs_output_dir
Configuration saved in ../dbfs_output_dir/config.json
Saving Model to ../dbfs_output_dir
The model is bigger than the maximum size per checkpoint (10GB) and is going to be split in 3 checkpoint shards. You can find where each parameters has been saved in the index located at ../dbfs_output_dir/pytorch_model.bin.index.json.
tokenizer config file saved in ../dbfs_output_dir/tokenizer_config.json
Special tokens file saved in ../dbfs_output_dir/special_tokens_map.json
Done.
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @dinhanhx I have updated the code. Apologies for missing information.

Comment: Please include the full traceback error.

Comment: @ewokx. Hi, I have updated the answer with the log. Please let me know if you need anything.

Comment: Your print statements should actually use ```%``` instead of the ```,```.  But that's just a nit.  That said, your try/except statement is catching the Exception.  Please run without the try/except.

Comment: @ewokx At first, I attempted the code without using an exception, but it still resulted in the same error. Subsequently, I added an exception, but the error message remained unchanged.